# numberOfRowsInSection not called after reloadData

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios4

I've seen various similar posts to this but none seem to match my situtation/solve the problem.

I have a tableview whose delegate and datasource are set to the VC it sits within.

On load this happily calls all the usual methods:

```
numberOfSectionsInTableView
numberOfRowsInSection
cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

however at this point the array containing my data is empty.

Once it is populated (after location lookup) `[tableView reloadData]` is called. This successfully fires:

```
numberOfSectionsInTableView
```

but neither of the following are recalled

```
numberOfRowsInSection
cellForRowAtIndexPath
```

I have even tried returning different results (0/1) in the `numberOfRowsInSection` method to try and force it with no result

Thanks for any help

Comment: is the return value of `numberOfSectionsInTableView` set to 0? it shouldn't happened not calling `-numberOfRowsInSection` and other datasource methods.

Comment: no its normally one, so therefore numberOfRowsInSection should always fire at least once

Answer (score 2):

I found the error.

The client had been playing with the code and changed the viewForHeaderInSection so that in some cases it was returning nothing (not even nil).

This must have prevented the other methods from firing, despite their being no exception or console log warning.